# How to call a Data Frame in R using the variable Value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have written the following code to compare Two Market, the code is working if we provide the Data Frame name individually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m52qI.jpg)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Market_SystemA))

 {

   A <- Market_SystemA[i,2]

   B <- Market_SystemB[i,3]



   MarketA <- data.frame(A)

   MarketB <- data.frame(B)

   #This is s fuction in R

   Compare_Function(MarketA,MarketB)

}
```

Comment: But it not working if we refer the Data Frame name using variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly,  but it seems like you are calling a `compare_function` on two  strings that refer to existing  data frames. To actually get the data frames  from the string, then you will need to use the `get` function which looks for an object that has a name that matches the string.

`MarketA <- get(A)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. This is my first post in Stack flow. You have got my requirement accurately. The solution is working perfectly but i have issue with the in the second market  data frame naming convention(SystemA_Russia). It working working only if i pass the data frame name in this format `SystemA_Russia`. can you please help me how to append this `` to my data frame name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Adding some code to your post might help me understand. Maybe `paste0('SystemA_', 'Russia')`

Comment: Sure, 
MarketA  <- get(A) - Working - A value is "India".  
MarketB  <- get(B)  - not working - B value is "`SystemA-India`" with grace accent. 
It's working if i apply the data frame name like this (`SystemA-India`) with grave accent manually.